# Minimize system of nonlinear equation (integral on exponent)

Tags: python, numpy, entropy, scipy-optimize

**General:**

I am using maximum entropy to find distribution for on positive integers vectors, I can estimate the mean and variance, and have three equation I am trying to find a and b,

**The equations:**

1. integral(exp(a*x^2+bx+c) from (0 , infinity))-1
2. integral(x*exp(a*x^2+bx+c)from (0 , infinity))- mean
3. integral(x^2*exp(a*x^2+bx+c) from (0 , infinity))- mean^2 - var

(integrals between [0,∞))

**The problem:**

I am trying to use numerical solver and I used fsolve of sympy
But I guess I am missing some knowledge.

**My code:**

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from scipy.optimize import *


def myFunction(x,*data):
    y = sym.symbols('y')
    m,v=data
    F = [0]*3
    x[0] = - abs(x[0])
    print(x)
    F[0] = (sym.integrate(sym.exp(x[0] * y ** 2 + x[1] * y + x[2]), (y, 0,sym.oo)) -1).evalf() 
    F[1] = (sym.integrate(y*sym.exp(x[0] * y ** 2 + x[1] * y + x[2]), (y, 0,sym.oo))-m).evalf()
    F[2] = (sym.integrate((y**2)*sym.exp(x[0] * y ** 2 + x[1] * y + x[2]), (y,0,sym.oo)) -v-m).evalf() 
    print(F)
    return F


data = (10,3.5) # mean and var for example
xGuess = [1, 1, 1]
z = fsolve(myFunction,xGuess,args = data)
print(z)
```

my result are not that accurate, is there a better way to solve it?

1. integral(exp(a*x^2+bx+c))-1 = 5.67659292676884
2. integral(x*exp(a*x^2+bx+c))- mean = −1.32123173796713
3. integral(x^2*exp(a*x^2+bx+c))- mean^2 - var = −2.20825624606312

Thanks

Comment: Is this a [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) distribution? the Gaussian formula (using the mean and the variance) can be written as exp(a*x2 + b*x +c), for instance a=-1/(2*sigma2) ...

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, i edited the question the boundary of the integral is from 0 to infinity

Comment: Have a look at [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). If you think your problem is non-convex, check out the [global optimization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#global-optimization) part.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten the problem replacing `sympy` with `numpy` and lambdas (inline functions).
Also note that in your problem statement you subtract the third equation with $mean^2$, but in your code you only subtract $mean$.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.integrate import quad


def myFunction(x,data):
    m,v=data
    F = np.zeros(3)  # use numpy array

    # use scipy.integrade.quad for integration of lambda functions
    # quad output is (result, error), so we just select the result value at the end
    F[0] = quad(lambda y: np.exp(x[0] * y ** 2 + x[1] * y + x[2]), 0, np.inf)[0] -1
    F[1] = quad(lambda y: y*np.exp(x[0] * y ** 2 + x[1] * y + x[2]), 0, np.inf)[0] -m
    F[2] = quad(lambda y: (y**2)*np.exp(x[0] * y ** 2 + x[1] * y + x[2]), 0, np.inf)[0] -v-m**2

    # minimize the squared error
    return np.sum(F**2)


data = (10,3.5) # mean and var for example
xGuess = [-1, 1, 1]
z = minimize(lambda x: myFunction(x, data), x0=xGuess,
             bounds=((None, 0), (None, None), (None, None)))  # use bounds for negative first coefficient
print(z)

# x: array([-0.99899311,  2.18819689,  1.85313181])
```

Does this seem more reasonable?